# Tor spawns a lot of obfs4proxy

Tags: openwrt, socks, tor

```
Hardware: Xiaomi Redmi AX6S (AX3200)
System: OpenWRT 23.05.3, kernel 5.15
```

I've configured `tor` to use `obfs4proxy` and `ss-redir` (shadowsocks) to use `simple-tls` plugin.

With no connections via `tor` and `ss-redir` both of them spawn lots of subprocesses, which utilize about 40% RAM. `pstree`:

```
|-ss-redir---simple-tls---7*[{simple-tls}]
|-tor-+-obfs4proxy---7*[{obfs4proxy}]
```

Why both of them spawn so many subprocesses? Why this number is 8 for both?

How to stop it, i.e. leave only one or two instances?

`/etc/tor/torrc:`

```
User tor
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.254.0.0/16
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 192.168.1.1:9040
TransPort 127.0.0.1:9040
DNSPort 127.0.0.1:9053
SOCKSPort 192.168.1.1:9050         # Tor socks-proxy
GeoIPFile /usr/share/tor/geoip
GeoIPv6File /usr/share/tor/geoip6
ExcludeExitNodes {RU},{UA},{BY},{KZ},{MD},{TM},{UZ},{AM},{KG}
ExitPolicy reject *:*
ExitPolicy reject6 *:*
#TransPort 192.168.1.1:9040

ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
```

`/etc/config/shadowsocks-libev`:

```
config ss_redir 'hi'
    option disabled '0'
    option server 'sss0'
    option local_address '0.0.0.0'
    option local_port '1100'
    option mode 'tcp_and_udp'
    option timeout '60'
    option fast_open '1'
    option verbose '1'
    option reuse_port '1'

config server 'sss0'
    option server 'xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq'
    option server_port '4443'
    option password 'SoMePaSsWoRd'
    option method 'chacha20-ietf-poly1305'
    option plugin '/root/execs/simple-tls'
    option plugin_opts 'c;key=/root/conf/serv.key;cert=/root/conf/serv.cert;fast-open;no-verify'
```

Comment: @paladin, how it can be related with the hardware?

Comment: Your hardware might have not enough performance reserves to run a Tor proxy. Subprocesses spawn now to decrease latency